# Gnome 42 installed on Snap Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, snap

I have Ubuntu 20.04 with gnome-42-2204 installed as snap package

```
# snap list --all
Name               Version             Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
bare               1.0                 5      latest/stable    canonical✓  base
code               1a5daa3a            146    latest/stable    vscode✓     classic
core20             20230801            2015   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core20             20220805            1611   latest/stable    canonical✓  base,disabled
core22             20230801            864    latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-38-2004    0+git.efb213a       143    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-3-38-2004    0+git.891e5bc       115    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
gnome-42-2204      0+git.ff35a85       141    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-81-g442e511     1535   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snap-store         3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7  558    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd              2.60.4              20290  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
```

Does it mean I can change to Gnome 42?
I currently use Gnome 3.36 and want to try newer Gnome without upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have Ubuntu 20.04 with gnome-42-2204 installed as snap package

This is a back-end library for snap apps, and is not the full GNOME desktop.

> Does it mean I can change to Gnome 42? I currently use Gnome 3.36 and want to try newer Gnome without upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

No you cannot do that in 20.04 (without breaking your installation). To get a newer version of GNOME, you will have to upgrade.